# WPF: Limit clickable area of checkbox to the checkbox only

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I am using a checkbox as follows:

```
<CheckBox Content="Reload Code Table Rules"
          IsChecked="{Binding ReloadCodeTableRules, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Currently the checked state will change if I click on either the checkbox or the label.  Is it possible to limit this to only change when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Did you try using RadioButton ?

Comment: Unless you can find a way to rewrite the datatemplate for the checkbox i dont know if it can be done. A while back i wanted the same thing. I remember just creating a seperate control that had a checkbox and label control.

Answer (score 2):

You could place the text in a separate `TextBlock` and wrap them together in a `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ReloadCodeTableRules, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="Reload Code Table Rules" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```